# JM H264 Reference Software quality drop

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264

I've just started messing around with the latest JM 18.4 tool for a bit but after I encode a sample yuv file the video comes out poor.(Everything is on default, I did a clean compile just to make sure I didn't change anything by accident) It turns gray at some frames and looks distorted. I know this isn't the program for encoding videos but I'm using it for my project because of other factors.

I tried playing the .264 file directly with ffplay and tried using ffmpeg to convert it into an .mp4 format video, both resulted in the same quality. If anyone could enlighten my carelessness I would be greatly appreciative.

-din

Comment: I would rather post this to [the JM bug tracker](http://ipbt.hhi.fraunhofer.de/) as well. We're also missing information about what exactly you're doing — your system, the sample file, what exact options you're using, how you muxed it to MP4, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it myself, I know I wasn't being too specific but it was because I'm very new to this video encoding thing and didn't know many things. The prblem was the encoder.cfg file that had a wrong configuration by default for my setup (Sequence type)